# Software that exports into multiple formats and sizes?

Tags: conversion, compression

Sorry if this is a bit of a vague question. But does anyone know a piece of software that will take one or preferably multiple videos and turn them into multiple formats and quality?

So video.mp4 would result in:

video.mp4 compressed 1080p
video.mp4 compressed 720p
video.wmv compressed 1080p
video.wmv compressed 720p
video.avi compressed 1080p
video.avi compressed 720p

etc

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking something that can do that at the same time and is reasonably well developed, then you are probably looking at `avconv`. It has the same base as `ffmpeg`, which has already been mentioned, but currently doesn't have a GUI (to the best of my knowledge, i've not gone looking, since i have no need for it).

Let's look at an example of how you would go to create a file format that you have described there.

```
avconv -i video.mp4 \
 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 3 -c:v libxvid -s hd720 -q:v 7 video720.avi \
 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 3 -c:v libxvid -s hd1080 -q:v 7 video1080.avi \
 ...
```

You can just go on and on adding bits, and it will do encoding in parallel (which is much more efficient approach than sequential encoding on the modern multicore systems).

I didn't give you an example of encoding into WMV, simply because i've never done that, and i have actually recompiled my `avconv` to disable this, but it is possible if you feel that it is important for your system.

Depending on your operating system the installation process will be different. On Debian and Ubuntu GNU/Linux you do that by just typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

But it may be necessary for you to build your own binaries. To do so you need to get the original source code from libav.org and then run:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/USERNAME/.local --bindir=/home/USERNAME/bin \
  --enable-gpl --enable-version3 \
  --enable-encoder=ENCODER
```

USERNAME is your username, and you can change bindir if you don't have bin in your execution path. You can also enable any encoder that you will need by checking which ones are available and adding them via `--enable-encoder`. To check available ones, just run:

```
./configure --list-encoders
```

But in all likelihood you will have no need to recompile unless you are doing something strange.

Answer (score 0):

[Ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) does that. Depending on what you're trying to do there are several other programs that come with an easy-to-use GUI ([XMedia Recode](http://www.xmedia-recode.de/en/), for instance).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Ill check out the GUI based XMedia Recode. Do you have any idea where tutorials might be to do the above task? Or just point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Hm i hardly use ffmpeg, but the documentation in the website would be a good point to start. Ffmpeg will require a bit reading in order to use it efficiently. Xmedia recode is designed to be easily accessible, but the amount of automatism you can achieve with it is nothing compared to ffmpeg. Xmedia recode is designed to be easily accessible, but the amount of automatism you can achieve with it is very limited compared to ffmpeg.

Comment: Sorry for the doubled sentence in the last comment, my phone did that ... XMedia Recode is pretty straight forward. You open a file, choose a format you want it to be converted to, adjust the settings if needed and click "add to queue". You can do this several times to add different output formats to the queue. When you're done, click "Encode" to have your queue processed. You can also define presets, if you'll need to encode to the same formats repeatedly in the future ...

Comment: All of that makes sense but it seems to be showing me profiles that all end up being MP4. I cant find how to queue it up as avi or wmv

Comment: You're talking about XMedia Recode right now, right? Take a look at the highlighted area in [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/cbnvuWP.png). Set the profile to "custom", then you can pick the desired output format under "format", including avi and wmv. The settings that are available depend on what profile you've set right there, so make sure to always select the profile you want first. I should also mention that the program's definition of a "profile" is pretty inacurate and indecisive, since they include both codecs, file and container formats in there ...